# Making + non-greedy?

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

Imagine I have the String

```
abcD
```

and I want to extract `abc` out of it. I thought of using

```
^(.+)D$
```

however then in matching group1, not only `abc`, but `abcD` is included - how to make the `.+` less greedy, so `D` is not included in the group? I know I could use `[^D]+`, but is this really the only way?

**Sorry, this was a reduced an bad test-case.**
Have a look at this sample (Java):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\{(.+?)\\})?$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("{a}{b}");

System.out.println(matcher.matches()); // true
```

Why does this match? Shouldn't the regular expression just allow one `{` and one `}` in the String in total? I want only things like `{< not } >}` to match.

Comment: Do you mean `^(.+)D$`? And which of the many flavors of regular expressions are you using?

Comment: It's not `.` that is greedy, but rather `+`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Of course, thanks! Nathan, OK, thanks, but then, any idea on how to change that behaviour?

Comment: Given that the `D` is outside of the capture, it should never been inside the resulting group.  Perhaps you have a misunderstanding about the match results?  For example, in JavaScript you get an array back from a `.match()`, where the first item is the entire matching string, and the *second* item is actually "group1".

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: The second question in my comment is the most important. Different regex engines have different capabilities and different syntaxes. What tool or language are you using?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Updated my post, please have a look at it, thanks :-)

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: "I want only things like `{< not } >}` to match." I don't think that's what you meant, but I can't tell what you did mean. Please fix the formatting.

Comment: It matches because the `.+?` will consume the `a}{b` part of your string--the rest is trivially matched. The `.` is what is causing you grief. Have you considered using a negated character class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a quantifier less greedy, you add a `?` after the quantifier:

```
^(.+?)D$
```

This depends, though, on your language or text editor. Different regex engines support different functionalities.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my sample was bad, now a full sample is provided above where I feel the `.+?` is greedy, though it shouldn't be - any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"D" is not included in the first group, it is included in the full pattern match.

The first group is "abc".

You can see a demo of this at http://rubular.com/r/oSnF17Jd39

Comment: you are right, it was my fault and a wrong sample - added a new one ;-)